# Unmet dependencies in Rhythmbox

Tags: dependencies, rhythmbox

I've been having problems with Rhythmbox, so I decided to uninstall and reinstall to see if it will work. I keep getting an error message during the installation that says

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rhythmbox : Depends: librhythmbox-core6 (= 2.98-0ubuntu5) but 2.98+git20121010.c331b2df-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
             Depends: rhythmbox-data (= 2.98-0ubuntu5) but 2.98+git20121010.c331b2df-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
             Depends: gir1.2-rb-3.0 (= 2.98-0ubuntu5) but 2.98+git20121010.c331b2df-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 is to be installed
             Recommends: rhythmbox-mozilla but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist but it is not going to be installed
             Recommends: rhythmbox-plugins but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this? Output from sudo apt-cache rhythmbox

```
rhythmbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.98-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
     2.98+git20121010.c331b2df-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.98-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you on? is the system up to date? Do you get this error when installing other software?

Comment: `2.98+git20121010.c331b2df` indicates to me you're not running the official packages. Please provide *all* information regarding the steps you've taken earlier. My guess is that you're running a PPA version of Rhythmbox. Please provide the output of `apt-cache policy rhythmox` run from the terminal in your question.

Comment: When I do that it outputs "rhythmbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.98-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
     2.98+git20121010.c331b2df-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz0 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.98-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main i386 Packages
" I should be running the official package. I've got it when I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04. I decided to uninstall it because it's had some Gstreamer problems, and Clementine was working fine. I like Rhythmbox better, so if you can help me that would be great. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: To alvar, I'm running 13.04. I recently upgraded yesterday, but it didn't upgrade succesfully, and everything works so-so, except Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 1):

#### Revert to the Ubuntu version

At some point in time you really have installed some PPA version of Rhythmbox, but you have deleted the PPA from the sources. Because the version currently installed is marked newer as the one Ubuntu is offering in the main repositories it is still running the PPA version. And because *new* dependencies have to be satisfied from the old PPA, you are getting conflicts.

To resolve this, try to revert to the Ubuntu version of the package as shown in the `apt-cache policy` output:

```
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox=2.98-0ubuntu5
```

and hopefully `apt-get` will suggest a solution to downgrade the other packages as well.

Comment: I've tried purging Rhythmbox to see if anything will happen, then I ran the command and it still comes up with this. http://paste.ubuntu.com/5844626/ I don't know how to reverse to previous packages.